# como guardar imagende codigo QR

Tags: android, android-studio, qrcode

Buenas tardes encontre un codigo que me genera y guarda una imagen QR, el problema esta que la imagen no me guarda.
Aqui esta el codigo:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean save;
            String result;
            try {
                String savePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/QRCode/";
                save = QRGSaver.save(savePath, "ImagenQR", bitmapResult, QRGContents.ImageType.IMAGE_JPEG);
                result = save ? "Imagen guardada" : "Image no guardada";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Edición**
Disculpen ya lo arregle, es solo agregar el permiso a un android mayor al 6.

Comment: Es importante revisar el LogCat para determinar algún posible error, saludos.